# R: Regex for identifying numbers within HTML chunk

Tags: r, regex

this is my first entry on stack overflow, so please be indulgent if my post might have some lack in terms of quality.

I want to learn some webscraping with R and started with a simple example --> Extracting a table from a Wikipedia site.

I managed to download the specific page and identified the HTML sections I am interested in:

```
<td style="text-align:right">511.000.000\n</td>
```

Now I want to extract the number in the data from the table by using regex. So i created a regex, which should match the structure of the number from my point of view:

```
pattern<-"\\d*\\.\\d*\\.\\d*\\.\\d*\\."
```

I also tried other variations but none of them found the number within the HTML code. I wanted to keep the pattern open as the numbers might be hundreds, thousand, millions, billions.

1. My questions: The number is within the HTML code, might it be
   necessary to include some code for the non-number code (which should
   not be extracted...)
2. What would be the correct version for the
   pattern to identify the number correctly?

Thank you very much for your support!!

Comment: Honestly, if you need to parse HTML content then use an HTML parser library from R.  Generally speaking, using regex to parse HTML is a bad idea.

Comment: Regarding first point it depends on your data structure. If you have to dig through a huge page some structural selector might be needed. But why not relying on a html parser in that case?

Comment: Thanky for your fast feedback. I will definitively consider these when going ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at your regex. You are assuming that the number will have 4 periods (`\\.`) in it, but in your own example there are only two periods. It's not going to match because while the asterisk marks `\\d` as optional (zero or more), the periods are not marked as optional. If you add a `?` modifier after the 3rd and 4th period, you may find that your pattern starts matching.

Comment: The OP might also find that, for example, content inside some of the actual tags gets returned as a match.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your fast feedback! This changes worked fine for this regex code!

Answer (score 1):

So many stars implies a lot of backtracking.
One point further, using `\\d*` would match more than 3 digits in any group and would also match a group with no digit.

Assuming your numbers are always integers, formatted using a `.` as thousand separator, you could use the following: `\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})*` (note the usage of non-capturing group construct `(?:...)` - implying the use of `perl = TRUE` in arguments, as mentioned in [Regular Expressions as used in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)).